# Animation on the IPad - What to use for something like the Alice in Wonderland Book?

Tags: ipad, animation, core-animation

Nood to ios/mac dev and come from 12 years of ms/.net dev. Interested in what tech would be used to do keyframe animation and something similar to the Alice in wonderland ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gew68Qj5kxw ) book available on ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A popular framework is cocos-2d for iOS which you can use to build something like the Alice book.

Comment: Thanks Steve - looks like a great start.

Answer (score 0):

All of that can be done in native code, with higher performance and faster loading times.

Cocos2d initiates a 2nd OpenGL Context, but UIView animations do not. If you want physics, implement them in UIKit. There is a UIKit tutorial for doing that.

I just thought I'd remove the misconception that you "need" cocos2d. However, Interface Builder can't rotate or zoom UI, but Cocos2d's editors can. If you want good tools, use Cocos2d instead.

Raw speed is iOS SDK multithreaded animations. Automatically handles it for you